# Convert TreeNodeCollection to List<TreeNode>

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

How can I Convert `TreeNodeCollection` to `List<TreeNode>`?

This isn't working.

```
ICollection tnc = treeview1.Nodes;
ICollection<TreeNode> tn = (ICollection<TreeNode>)tnc;
List<TreeNode> list = new List<TreeNode>(tn);
```

Exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode]'.

Comment: Why would you need to?

Comment: @SamAxe, tree Searching.

Comment: Without LINQ you're stuck with a `for` loop (or variant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten a `TreeNodeCollection` using the following helper class which is written in .NET 2.0:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class NodeHelper
{
    public static List<TreeNode> ToList(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        List<TreeNode> list = new List<TreeNode>();
        foreach (TreeNode node in ToIEnumerable(nodes))
            list.Add(node);
        return list;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> ToIEnumerable(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode c1 in nodes)
        {
            yield return c1;
            foreach (TreeNode c2 in ToIEnumerable(c1.Nodes))
            {
                yield return c2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example, the following code will flatten the whole node hierarchy of `treeView1` into a list:

```
List<TreeNode> list = NodeHelper.ToList(treeView1.Nodes);
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is:

```
List<TreeNode> treeNodeList = treeNodeCollection.OfType<TreeNode>().ToList();
```

Another:

```
List<TreeNode> treeNodeList = treeNodeCollection.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList();
```

foreach Loop:

```
List<TreeNode> treeNodeList = new List<TreeNode>();
foreach (TreeNode item in treeNodeCollection)
    treeNodeList.Add(item);
```

Comment: .net 2.0 required.

Comment: use foreach loop